# cancel comment in angular and change view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

when i click on edit button the view is changed by ng-if how to go back by clicking cancel button

```
    <div class="timeline-body">
                <div marked="cmnt.content" class="markdown" ng-if = "editPostComment != $index "  ></div>

                <!--Edit comment-->
                  <div class="commentBox" ng-if = "editPostComment == $index "  >
                    <textarea 
                    rows="10" > {{cmnt.content}}</textarea>
                    <div class="hints">
                      <span class="boldtext">**Bold**</span>
                      <span class="italictext">_itlaics_</span>
                      <span class="striktext">~~strike~~</span>
                      <span class="codetext">'code'</span>
                      <span class="codetext">'''preformatted'''</span>
                      <span class="quotetext">>quote</span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="comment-btns">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left" ng-class="{'loading': commentig}" ng-disabled="commentig" ng-click="cancel()">Submit</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left cancel-edit" ng-class="{'loading': commentig}" ng-disabled="commentig" ng-click = "cancelEdit()">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your route change when clicking on edit comment, you can do it like in javascript. Try this

```
$scope.cancel = function(){
    $window.history.back();
}
```

But if it only depend to the nf-if condition you can set the value of editPostComment to be different to $index as below

```
$scope.cancel = function(editPostComment){
    editPostComment = null;
}
```

and then change the cancel button to

```
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-left" ng-class="{'loading': commentig}" ng-disabled="commentig" ng-click="cancel(editPostComment)">Submit</button>
```

Comment: no i don't route change i gust need to make the view when the user clicks on cancel btn the changes happens when ng-if = "editPostComment != $index " but that doesn't happen , i just want to change between the views